# Does the quadratic covariation process define a measure?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In the context of stochastic integration (when we define the space $L^2(M)$), we define the (possibly infinite) measure $$P_M = P \otimes [M]$$ by
$$E_M[Y] = E\left[\int_0^\infty Y_s(\omega) d[M]_s(\omega)\right]$$
 where $M$ is a square integrable martingale.

My question is: why did they choose this notation? I know that if we have two measures $Q, R$ then $Q \otimes R$ is the measure defined as $Q \otimes R(A \times B) = Q(A)R(B)$ and then we extend this measure in a unique way to the sigma algebra generated by the sets in the form $A \times B$.

So I guess that there are some similarities between this definition and the previous one, and that $[M]$ can be used to define some sort of measure on $((0, \infty), \mathcal B(0, \infty))$ (where $\mathcal B(0, \infty)$ is the borel sigma algebra on $(0, \infty)$). One guess could be
$$[M](A) = \int_0^\infty 1_A(s) d[M]_s$$

but I would not know how to prove that this definition gives raise to the same expression for $E_M$.

So my question are:  Does $[M]$ define a measure ? If so, how? And how to show that it gives raise to the same expectation as before?

Comment: Seems to me, a better notation should be $$E_{P_M}[Y] = E_P\left[\int_0^\infty Y_s(\omega) d[M]_s(\omega)\right]$$, and $$P_M(A) = E_P\left[\int_0^\infty 1_A(s) d[M]_s\right]$$. In that case, $P_M$ define a measure on $\Omega\times \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Jay.H I agree, that is more precise :) What about my questions though? :-) I'd love if you have time to write down an answer :)

Comment: You can say that $[M]$ defines a measure for a given path $\omega$, so precisely, $[M](A)$ should be written as $[M]_{\omega}(A)$. However, the original $E_M$ (which should have been written as $E_{P_M}$) corresponds to a measure $P_M$.  $P_M$ and $[M]$ are different, loosely speaking, we have $P_M(B) = E_P([M]_{\omega}(B|\omega))$

Comment: @Jay.H Yeah, I know, I wrote that. My point was: Is it possible to define $[M](A)$ such that defining $P_M = P \otimes [M]$ results in the expectation defined above?

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Yeah, I guess the notation $$P_M = P \otimes [M]$$ is confusing, it should be emphasized that, this is not the usual product measure.  On the other hand, they used $\otimes$, not $\times$ (which is the usual notation for product measure).

Comment: And I guess in general, the answer to your question should be no, except for some special cases, like Brownian motion.

Comment: @Jay.H Actually I always indicated the product measure as $P \otimes Q$. Anyhow this is just a weird notation then?